# Are there any pci-e controllers that take like a SPI signal, or USB and then lets me hookup a pci-e x1 card to it?

Tags: usb, spi, gpio, pcie, controller

I am wondering if such a thing exists, as I could really use one to hookup to a SoC I am designing a board around, as it would allow me to take like a pci-e tv controller, pci-e ethernet card, pci-e GPU.
It should take in some signal a mobile SoC can provide, like SPI, USB, or straight driving it from gpios(probably slow) and then outpu a pci-e x1 lane(s) or more.
Does somebody know of such a thing, that is reasonably priced = < $12?

Thanks

Comment: Not gonna happen. Use a more capable SoC.

Comment: Why is that "not gonna happen" I know they exist, just can't find them anymore.

Comment: I would be surprised if it existed. It would be a bit like trying to find a hook to append a big travel trailer to a bicycle. You should look for a cheap single board computer with pci-e instead.

Comment: Thats the thing, I do NOT want to use singleboard computers.
I want to design it myself, otherwise, what would be the fun of it?

Comment: I hope you have documentation for that GPU, you aren't trying to use a desktop GPU for example.

Comment: *"singleboard computers. I want to design it myself, otherwise, what would be the fun of it?"* - you have quite a gap between your fun intentions and reality. Designing singleboard computer is far from fun, it is a serious engineering that requires good education, experience, and teamwork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the PCIe root complex is a part of the SoC. If PCIe is needed you just select an SoC that has it built-in. Example: i.MX6, Sitara.

It could of course be designed in an FPGA and connected by SPI or anything to the SoC, but that defeats the main point of PCIe, which is high-bandwidth applications. Having SPI on the host side could work but would make in unbearably slow.

Comment: Aside from being unbearably slow such a system would have the problem of needing a rewrite for the drivers. Drivers for PCIe perhipherals expect the perhipheral to be memory mapped (or in some cases IO mapped on CPUs that support it) and they expect the perhiperal to be able to do bus master DMA to/from main memory.

Comment: @PeterGreen, actually the USB3.0 bandwidth kind-of matches the one-lane PCIe-1X. However the rest of your remark is spot on, there is no way to map/reverse the USB pipe/endpoint framework back into PCIe bus-mastering architecture.